# Atualizar (refresh) em uma div_id de 2 em 2 seg usando greasemonkey userscript

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como atualizar uma div_id de 2 em 2 segundos sem precisar dar reload da página inteira usando um userscript.

```
<div id="right">
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como atualizar uma DIV com Ajax/JS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153778/como-atualizar-uma-div-com-ajax-js), [Como criar um site sem recarregar a cada clique num link?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6626)

Comment: Como o @wmsouza mencionou, em sua página há essa possibilidade, já em páginas que não são de sua autoria fica mais complicado, pois não sabemos da onde vem o conteúdo.